# Border on html table with colspan

Tags: html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, layout, html-table

I made the table below:

[image: html table]

It's using bootstrap classes "table table-bordered", the second **th** column, have a **colspan="49"**, but on the end of lines doesn't show the borders.

EDIT: Here is the code

```
function loadData() { 
    var id = $("#id").val(); 
    $.ajax({ url: '192.168.31.253/gestao_web/table/load_table/'; + id, 
             dataType: "html", 
             type: "GET", 
             success: function (data) { 
                          return $("#data_recipe").html(data); 
                      }, 
             error: function (data) { 
                          console.log(data); 
                    } 
      }); 
}
```

Comment: did you use a script to generate this ? could you please share it perhaps.

Comment: script only lodas the body-table content generated by php.

 function loadData() {
            var id = $("#id).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://192.168.31.253/gestao_web/table/load_table/' + id,
                dataType: "html",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    return $("#data_recipe").html(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }

Comment: I have edited your post with your comment (adding code)

Comment: Is it really `"table table-brodered"`? Is the typo *here* where you wrote your question, or in your HTML?

Comment: Thanks Marc Giroux

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, u can trick it with inserting some hidden `value` at the last right empty column (before end of lines), u can use css `display:none` and  tag.

for example :

```
<span style="display:none;"> (hidden value here) </span>
```

hope this answer, could fix your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was the php that was generating the incorrectly table.

Thank you all.